# How to Pass Array to another activity?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-emulator, android-widget

I know that we can able to pass the any object with its value to another activity with the method `putExtra()` and `getExtra` methods.
but now I want to know whether is it possible to pass the array to the another `Activity` or not?
Or if it is then let me know how I can pass the array to the another `Activity` ?
Thanks.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

```
Bundle b = new Bundle();
b.putStringArray(key, new String[]{value1, value2});
Intent i=new Intent(context, Class);
i.putExtras(b);
```

And for receiveing

```
Bundle b = this.getIntent().getExtras();
String[] array=b.getStringArray(key);
```

Comment: ok Nice. But what if i want to pass the Array without value. I mean if i have already store the value in to the array and now if i want to pass it to another activiy by just name of the array then ?

Comment: Have a look at this page http://androidhub.wordpress.com/2011/08/03/android-intents-for-passing-data-between-activities-part-2

Answer (score 4):

The [`Bundle`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Bundle.html) class has many putXxxxArray() methods.

1. [putBooleanArray](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Bundle.html#putBooleanArray%28java.lang.String,%20boolean%5B%5D%29)
2. [putByteArray](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Bundle.html#putByteArray%28java.lang.String,%20byte%5B%5D%29)
3. [putCharArray](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Bundle.html#putCharArray%28java.lang.String,%20char%5B%5D%29)
4. [putCharSequenceArray](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Bundle.html#putCharSequenceArray%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.CharSequence%5B%5D%29)
5. [putDoubleArray](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Bundle.html#putDoubleArray%28java.lang.String,%20double%5B%5D%29)
6. [putFloatArray](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Bundle.html#putFloatArray%28java.lang.String,%20float%5B%5D%29)
7. [putIntArray](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Bundle.html#putIntArray%28java.lang.String,%20int%5B%5D%29)
8. [putLongArray](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Bundle.html#putLongArray%28java.lang.String,%20long%5B%5D%29)
9. [putParcelableArray](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Bundle.html#putParcelableArray%28java.lang.String,%20android.os.Parcelable%5B%5D%29)
10. [putShortArray](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Bundle.html#putShortArray%28java.lang.String,%20short%5B%5D%29)
11. [putStringArray](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Bundle.html#putStringArray%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D%29)

If you are looking to pass some sort of `Object`, you should look at the `Parcelable` interface, as your Objects will need to implement it.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, you should know two issues:

- in order to send sth via an intent it must be parcelable
- even if an object is pacelable, there is limitation to the amount of data you can send via an intent.

A possible approach could be to have a static structure where you could store your data and pass with the intent only an index to that data. Using this index the new activity could get access to those data. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

Please see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4429036/passing-string-array-between-android-activities) question. Basically:

```
Bundle b=new Bundle();
b.putStringArray(key, new String[]{value1, value2});
Intent i=new Intent(context, Class);
i.putExtras(b);
```

To retrieve:

```
Bundle b=this.getIntent().getExtras();
String[] array=b.getStringArray(key);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
 Intent intent = new Intent();
 Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
 bundle.putSerializable("bundle",Parceble Object);
 intent.putExtra(String key, String[] values);
 intent.putExtras(bundle);
```

And for different types of array look [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Bundle.html#putBooleanArray%28java.lang.String,%20boolean%5b%5d%29).

Thnx

Comment: ok. Should i also have to send the value with the array ? It only name can make to fetch data ?

Comment: here, there are static value you are given to the array during passing it. But in my case, i don't know how many values are there in the array. Means it can be changed based on the activity call. So how to define the range and values of that array ???

Comment: if you don'tknow the size of array at runtime then you can use  ArrayList<String> like, public void putStringArrayList (String key, ArrayList<String> value)

Comment: So will i pass that array lise from one activity to another ?

Comment: instead of that if i create bean class and use the getter setter methods for that then is it a good idea ????

Comment: yes, you will pass arraylist from one activity to other activity. And if you want to pass the other data different type of data then you can pass it in object, but if you want to pass only a single array then putStringArrayList (String key, ArrayList<String> value)  is better. :-)