# How to lanch an activity with parameters?

Tags: java, android, constructor

I have created an Activity class and defined a constructor:

```
   public class Spinner_Name extends Activity{

        List<String> listSp;
        public Spinner_Name(List<String> list)
        {
            listSp = new ArrayList<String>();
            listSp = list;
        }


        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.spinner_layout);

        }
}
```

And I want to call that Activity from this Activity:

```
 public class MAIN extends Activity{

            List<String> listSp;


            @Override
            public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                setContentView(R.layout.spinner_layout);
                 listSp = new ArrayList<String>();
                  listSp.add("a");

            }
    }
```

But when I run the application this message shows up:

> Unfortunately, Main has been stopped

When I delete the argument from the constructor the application runs successfully. How do I get the activity to run with the argument??

Comment: listSp.add("a); is not correct. complete your invited coma listSp.add("a");

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[1)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3303512/3736955) "You never construct an activity directly, so you can't use it to pass in parameters." You do things on `onCreate()`.

[2)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3913720/3736955) You can send parameters from one activity to another using `Bundle`, for example send `int`:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(FirstActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
Bundle b = new Bundle();
b.putInt("key", 1); //Your id
intent.putExtras(b); //Put your id to your next Intent
startActivity(intent);
finish();
```

and get that value from new opened activity:

```
Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();
int value = b.getInt("key");
```

[3)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6087312/3736955)To send List, you need to copy `list` into `array` and send `array`:

```
List<String> a;
String[] b = new String[a.size()];
a.toArray(b);
Bundle c=new Bundle();
c.putStringArray("myList", b);     
Intent intent = new Intent(FirstActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
intent.putExtras(c)
startActivity(intent);
finish();
```

Get array ([check](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7257726/3736955)):

```
Bundle b=getIntent().getExtras();
String[] myNewList=b.getStringArray("myList");
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not write constructors for classes extending `Activity`. You should initialize any fields either where they are declared or in `onCreate()`. If you need to pass an `ArrayList` from one activity to another, you should use `putExtra` to store the `ArrayList` with an `Intent` and `getExtra` to retrieve it back again.

Comment: thank you , but please mor descripe for me and by code

Answer (score 0):

I think this isn't the solution for your problem, but the two lines don't make sense:

```
listSp = new ArrayList<String>();
listSp = list;
```

You create a new ArrayList-Object and afterwards overwrite immediately the reference. So the garbage collector will throw it away.

Comment: Currently you have two objects: the parameter-ArrayList-object, which is forwarded in the constructor and the one you create with the line `listSp = new ArrayList<String>();`

Comment: I ' m not shure.Baschdl,I once delete the implementation code in constructor and run it,but i see error of this!!!!

Comment: I think it should look like this:
`List<String> listSp;  
        public Spinner_Name(List<String> list)  
        {  
            listSp = list;  
        }  
`

Comment: this can been according of your suggest.ok,but no problem create,

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand this?

Comment: It mean this: your suggest code is correctly and it is beeter and my code is coorect and no problem create accroding to your comment, but problem is in other ...

Comment: This code lines aren't responsible for the bug, but will cause other problems.