# Spinner to String to Intent to Array . Why won't this Intent work?

Tags: android, arrays, string, android-intent

Why won't the intent work properly? MainActivity is a graph that originally plotted one of the lines from an array (series1Numbers).I have another class (Main2Activity) with a spinner that i would like to have populate the (series1numbers) Array in MainActivity thereby generating my graph. Currently the graph line for (series1numbers) is blank which makes alot of sense because i have not been able to figure out how to populate it with the single number from (Main2Activity). I have searched and searched and not been able to connect the dots for this issue.

Main Activity.java

```
package com.example;
import java.util.Arrays;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import com.androidplot.series.XYSeries;
import com.androidplot.xy.LineAndPointFormatter;
import com.androidplot.xy.SimpleXYSeries;
import com.androidplot.xy.XYPlot;

/**
* The simplest possible example of using AndroidPlot to plot some data.
*/
public class MainActivity extends Activity
{

private XYPlot mySimpleXYPlot;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{

super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.main);
Intent intename = getIntent();
String name = (String) intename.getSerializableExtra("series1Numbers");



// initialize our XYPlot reference:
mySimpleXYPlot = (XYPlot) findViewById(R.id.mySimpleXYPlot);

// Create a couple arrays of y-values to plot:
Number[] series1Numbers ={name};
Number[] series2Numbers = {-4, -4, -5, -4, -4, -4, -3, -7, -4, -2, -4, -5, -5, -5};

// Turn the above arrays into XYSeries':
XYSeries series1 = new SimpleXYSeries(Arrays.asList(series1Numbers), 
// SimpleXYSeries takes a List so turn our array into a List
SimpleXYSeries.ArrayFormat.Y_VALS_ONLY, 
// Y_VALS_ONLY means use the element index as the x value
"Series1");                             
// Set the display title of the series

// same as above
XYSeries series2 = new SimpleXYSeries(Arrays.asList(series2Numbers), SimpleXYSeries.ArrayFormat.Y_VALS_ONLY, "Series2");

// Create a formatter to use for drawing a series using LineAndPointRenderer:
LineAndPointFormatter series1Format = new LineAndPointFormatter(
        Color.rgb(0, 200, 0),                   // line color
        Color.rgb(0, 100, 0),                   // point color
        null);                                  // fill color (none)

// add a new series' to the xyplot:
mySimpleXYPlot.addSeries(series1, series1Format);

// same as above:
mySimpleXYPlot.addSeries(series2,
        new LineAndPointFormatter(Color.rgb(0, 0, 200), Color.rgb(0, 0, 100), null));


// reduce the number of range labels
mySimpleXYPlot.setTicksPerRangeLabel(3);

// by default, AndroidPlot displays developer guides to aid in laying out your plot.
// To get rid of them call disableAllMarkup():
mySimpleXYPlot.disableAllMarkup();
```

}

Main2Activity.java

```
package com.example;


import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener;

public class Main2Activity extends Activity implements OnItemSelectedListener {

//TextView series1Numbers ;
Spinner spin;
String[] series1Numbers = { "-1", "-2", "-3", "-4", "-5",
   "-6", "-7", "-8" , "-9" , "-10" };
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.main2);

//series1Numbers  = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.series1Numbers );

Spinner spin = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
spin.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

ArrayAdapter<String> aa = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, series1Numbers);

spin.setAdapter(aa);
}

@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
// series1Numbers .setText(items[position]);
    if (position == 1){
      Intent intentObj = new Intent(Main2Activity.this, MainActivity.class);
      intentObj.putExtra("series1Numbers", series1Numbers);
      startActivity(intentObj);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Bundle b=new Bundle();
b.putStringArray(key, new String[]{value1, value2});
Intent i=new Intent(context, Class);
i.putExtras(b);
```

In order to read:

```
Bundle b=this.getIntent().getExtras();
String[] array=b.getStringArray(key);
```

Hope this will help you. :)

For more info., Refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4429036/passing-string-array-between-android-activities).

Comment: I do not understand how to implement this. Do I insert the first part in the onselect of the spinner?

Comment: yes,include first part in the `onItemSelected()` of the spinner, and pass the string array in bundle.(in your case series1Numbers).