# How to pass text from activity to another?

Tags: java, android

I want on the first Activity (in the layout to write) what is your name?! when a person write his name when he movie to anther Activity it should appear Hello(THE NAME)! how should i do this?

Answer (score 3):

This is how you call the intent with a parameter

```
Intent search = new Intent(FirstActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
search.putExtra("param_a", content1);
startActivity(search);
```

Comment: well the ans was for you to get started , either i copy paste the answer or you refer this link and get complete info :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4429036/passing-string-array-between-android-activities

Comment: the param_a is NAME and content is the valuo?

Comment: check the link , hope it explains everything

Comment: @down voter : please leave a reason or suggestion for downvote

Answer (score 2):

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
     @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
          //some stuff

          //Note : start the activity from an event (onClick per example)
          String stringObject = "Foo"; //or a String you get from your editText
          Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, OtherActivity.class);
           i.putExtra("name", stringObject);
           startActivity(i);
     }
}



public class OtherActivity extends Activity {
         @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
              //some stuff

               Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras(); 
               String name = "";

               if (extras != null){
                name = extras.getString("name");
                myTextView.setText(name);
              }

         }
    }
```

Comment: Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, OtherActivity.class);
            i.putExtra("name", is that the name that i have?);
           startActivity(i);

Comment: stringObject represents the name you get of the user. You have to stock this name in a `String` object. Example : `String stringObject="Foo";`

Comment: also in the anther activity i have a textview in the layout(what should i do to apper ) the name:a sentence!

Comment: `myTextView.setText(stringObject);`

Comment: should i write myTextView.setText(stringObject+"any thing i want?");

Comment: WOW thanq! :))))))) u r very fastt

Comment: Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, OtherActivity.class);
            i.putExtra("name", stringObject);
           startActivity(i); thats on the first but on the second i put myTextView.setText(stringObject);stringObject that from the first and when i do this its comes red under stringObject

Comment: what i should do in this case?

Comment: i did what u showed me now i will c, running the broject on the imlutor