# transferring data from string arrays into another activity

Tags: android

I have a fragment with a recycler view and an adaptor that accesses my string arrays, so that they are shown in the recycler view. My question is how can I transfer the data held in these arrays to a new activity, so when the user clicks on the selected item it then brings up more information held in these arrays.  I am not sure how it can be done, I have tried putting the values into an array list but can't seem to get it to work, as I am new to this.  Thank you in advance

This is my fragment

```
public class EventCalenderFragment extends Fragment {

RecyclerView recyclerView;
EventCalenderAdapter adapter;


public EventCalenderFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    adapter = new EventCalenderAdapter(getActivity());

}



@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    final View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_event_calender, container, false);
    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) v.findViewById(R.id.recycler);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
    return v;
}


}
```

This is my adapter

```
public class EventCalenderAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<EventCalenderAdapter.ViewHolder> {


String[] title;
String[] time_start;
String[] time_finish;
String[] date;
String[] description;
String[] loc_lat;
String[] loc_long;

static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    CardView cardView;
    TextView titleView;
    TextView auxView1;

    public ViewHolder(CardView card) {
        super(card);
        cardView = card;
        titleView = (TextView) card.findViewById(R.id.text1);
        auxView1 = (TextView) card.findViewById(R.id.text2);
    }
}

public EventCalenderAdapter (Context context) {

    title = context.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.title);
    time_start = context.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.time_start);
    time_finish = context.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.time_finish);
    date = context.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.date);
    description = context.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.description);
    loc_lat = context.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.loc_lat);
    loc_long = context.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.loc_long);

}

@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int i) {
    CardView v = (CardView) LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.event_task, parent, false);
    return new ViewHolder(v);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder viewHolder, final int i) {
    final Context context = viewHolder.titleView.getContext();
    viewHolder.titleView.setText(title[i]);
    viewHolder.auxView1.setText("Date: "+ date[i] + " Start: " + time_start[i] + " Finish: " + time_finish[i]);

    viewHolder.cardView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            ((OnEventView) context).eventView(i);
        }
    });

}
@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return title.length;
}


}
```

and this is the fragment I would like to access the data

```
public class EventViewFragment extends Fragment {

public static final String DEFAULT_FRAGMENT_TAG = "eventViewFragment";
static final String EVENT_ID = "eventId";

View rootView;
TextView title;
TextView description;
TextView date_time;
TextView location;

long eventId;

public static EventViewFragment newInstance(long id) {
    EventViewFragment fragment = new EventViewFragment();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putLong(EventViewActivity.VIEW_EVENTID, id);
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Bundle arguments = getArguments();
    if (arguments != null) {
        eventId = arguments.getLong(EventViewActivity.VIEW_EVENTID, 0L);
    }
    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        eventId = savedInstanceState.getLong(EVENT_ID);
    }
}

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    outState.putLong(EVENT_ID, eventId);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_event_view, container, false);
    rootView = v.getRootView();
    title = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.title);
    description = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.description);
    date_time = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.time_date);
    location =  (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.location);

    date_time.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

        }
    });

    location.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

        }
    });

    return v;
}
}
```

Comment: Are you transferring data between fragments or activities?

Comment: why do you want to transfer complete array just transfer selected item data like descrption[i]

Comment: It's a new fragment in a new activity, if that makes sense.

Comment: All the data from the arrays will be shown in the next screen

Comment: then create arrays in activity and transfer it to adapter in constructor in that scenario you can recreate number of fragments and no need to transfer  data

Comment: possible duplicate [Transfer data from one Activity to Another Activity Using Intents](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4429036/passing-string-array-between-android-activities)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once try as follows
In the first activity

```
Intent i=new Intent(getActivity(),NextActivity.class);
 i.putStringArrayListExtra("title", (ArrayList) Arrays.asList(title));
 i.putStringArrayListExtra("time_start",(ArrayList)Arrays.asList(time_start));
  i.putStringArrayListExtra("time_finish",(ArrayList)Arrays.asList(time_finish));
    i.putStringArrayListExtra("date",(ArrayList)Arrays.asList(date));
    i.putStringArrayListExtra("description",(ArrayList)Arrays.asList(description));
    i.putStringArrayListExtra("loc_lat",(ArrayList)Arrays.asList(loc_lat));
    i.putStringArrayListExtra("loc_long",(ArrayList)Arrays.asList(loc_long));
```

And in the next activity

```
 List<String> title1=getIntent().getStringArrayListExtra("title");
 ........................................

..........................................
```

Hope this will helps you.

Comment: Whereabouts in the first activity should I put the code @nag

Comment: @NickFallows If you want to use total data in the next activity then you can directly access from resources same as in first activity.

Comment: the data for the item that was clicked will be shown in more detail, not every bit of data

Answer (score 0):

use [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html) class it may be helpfull to transfer a data any where in a application