# pass a selected value in a spinner array to another class Android

Tags: java, android, arrays, android-intent, spinner

im building an app that has self destructing images and i am trying to pass  the value selected from the spinner to another class

```
final String titles[] = {"1 Second","2 Seconds", "3 Seconds","4 Seconds","5 Seconds","6 Seconds","7 Seconds", "8 seconds, "9 seconds", 10 seconds};
    mSeconds = (Spinner) view.findViewById(R.id.secondsSpinner);
    ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, titles);
    arrayAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

mSeconds.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
mSeconds.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView, View selectedItemView, int position, long id) {
        int secondsToUse = position + 1;
    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView) {
        // do nothing
    }

});
```

my intent method:

```
Intent recipientsIntent = new Intent(getActivity(), RecipientsActivity.class);
 recipientsIntent.putExtra("key1", titles);
                      startActivity(recipientsIntent);
```

how can i pass the value selected to another class? my method passes the whole array not the item selected.

Comment: What value u have to pass from your sample code?

Comment: @ImMathan what ever the value the user selects from the spinner

Comment: possible duplicate of [Passing string array between android activities](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4429036/passing-string-array-between-android-activities)

Comment: @smithyy did you try to google before posting here. Look at the api references I posted...

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html

Comment: "pass an array to another class" do you really want the whole array? Or the selected value?

Comment: @weston selected value

Comment: @weston please see my edited question above

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Spinner.getSelectedItem();
```

Will get you the selected item .

```
Intent recipientsIntent = new Intent(getActivity(), RecipientsActivity.class);
                recipientsIntent.putExtra("spinnerItem", Spinner.getSelectedItem());
                startActivity(recipientsIntent);
```

If you need extra logic behind this lmk.. Also `Spinner.getSelectedItem()` will return an object. You'll need to cast this to whatever you're expecting. A string for example... `Spinner.getSelectedItem().toString()`

To pass an int in an intent:

```
Intent recipientsIntent = new Intent(getActivity(), RecipientsActivity.class);
recipientsIntent.putExtra("YOUR_INT_KEY", secondsToUse);
startActivity(recipientsIntent);
```

The reason your int isn't working in your intent is because it's a local variable to the onItemSelected() Function. make it a member variable or put it outside onItemSelected

Comment: where do i add `Spinner.getSelectedItem().toString()` in my onItemSelect method

Comment: you would put that code outside of your onItemSelect interface method. You would want to put things in your onItemSelect method if you're planning on doing something with the selected value immediately. Or if you're planning on storing the value to be used later. If I knew what you were trying to do with the selected item It'd be easier to guide you lol

Comment: Yes thanks I will be putting it in a timer so I want to take the selected value to another class upload it to parse and then get it back into another class an put it into a timer

Comment: so in onItemSelected one of the parameters returns a view I believe. Or a an object value/position. Use that value and pass it via an intent to your other class. If you use the position you could get the value of the object you want from the array you used to populate the Spinner. Then do what you want with it!

If you need more help, lmk. Otherwise if my answer was helpful in solving your problem could you mark it as the accepted answer? Thanks!

Comment: please see my edited question above where would i put your answer `Spinner.getSelectedItem().toString()`

Comment: Like I said you could use position to get the position of the item selected in your array you used to populate the spinner. Put that code in onItemSelected

Comment: it has red line uner getSelectedItem()

Comment: it says not static method  getSelectedItem() can not be referenced from static context

Comment: don't put getSelectedItem in onItemSelected... that's for outside the interface. in onItemSelected use your position variable to reference the position in your array and use that.

Comment: it wont let me use my variable secondsToUse in the intent, can you please show me how in your answer above

Answer (score 1):

```
final String titles[] = {"1 Second","2 Seconds", "3 Seconds","4 Seconds","5 Seconds","6 Seconds","7 Seconds", "8 seconds, "9 seconds", 10 seconds};  
Bundle b=new Bundle();
b.putStringArray(key, titles);
Intent i=new Intent(context, Class);
i.putExtras(b);
startActivity(i);
```

In order to read:

```
Bundle b=this.getIntent().getExtras();
String[] array=b.getStringArray(key);
```

Comment: i would like to pass the selected number from the array to another class

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code dis shut work

To send:

```
Intent intentS=new Intent(getActivity(), Main_ExerciseLibrary_Overview_Activity.class);
                    intentS.putExtra("yourInt",Value);
                    startActivity(intentS);
```

TO Receive:

```
Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();
    int myint = b.getInt("yourInt");
```

Comment: i would like to get the selected number from array to pass over to another class

Comment: no it did not i passed in secondsToUse but it did not work

Comment: Wait are you passing a int or string?

Comment: i have a string array but i am passing an int position i declared secondsToUse and a global variable and have now passed that through