# Passing bidimensional String Array variable from 1 activity to another

Tags: android, arrays, android-studio, android-intent, bundle

I have a bidimensional String array that has mass data (sizes are `[40][8]` to be exact) in my Activity A. I want to pass the whole array to Activity B. I've tried this solution: [Passing string array between android activities](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4429036/passing-string-array-between-android-activities)

but the problem is it is creating an array inside. I want to pass my original bidimensional array that contains `[40][8]` values. Can I do that?

EDIT:

my String array is a 2 dimensional array.

Comment: you have two string arrays or a bidimensional string array?

Comment: and, which is the problem on creating a new array in activityB? I don't get it

Comment: i have only 1 string array. it is a 2 dimensional array. Sorry, i forgot to mention that.

Comment: I can create a new array on activity B. the problem is that i dont know how to pass my 2 dimensional array from activity A to a newly created 2 dimensional array on activity B. (the 2 dimensional array on activity B has nothing in it (null) i want to fill it with my 2 dimensional array from activity A.)

Comment: is it still confusing? Im sorry ...

Comment: no don't worry, now I got it and replied :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your array is `bidimensional` and `bidimensional array` are `serializable`, you can use a `bundle`:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, activityB.class);
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putSerializable("myArray", myBidimensionalArray);
intent.putExtras(bundle);
```

and in `activityB` you can simply call:

```
Intent passed = getIntent();
Bundle bundle = passed.getExtras();
String[][] myPassedArray = (String[][]) bindle.getSerializable("myArray");
```

and you are done